# Thinking-Sphinx & Rails - Content not indexed anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a Rails application that indexes classifeds ads. I'm using thinking-sphinx.
Yesterday, I realized that my ads are not getting indexed anymore. I'm a beginner in Rails so I don't know exactly what is happening here...

We can see the issue in searchd.query.log file :

```
[Sun May 19 22:19:46.432 2013] 0.000 sec [all/5/ext 0 (0,1000000000)] [ad_core]

[Sun May 19 22:19:46.446 2013] 0.000 sec [all/5/ext 0 (0,1000000000)] [ad_core]

[Sun May 19 22:19:46.455 2013] 0.000 sec [all/4/ext **21** (0,1000000000)] [ad_core]

[Sun May 19 22:19:46.590 2013] 0.000 sec [all/5/ext 0 (0,25)] [ad_core]

[Mon May 20 01:21:50.385 2013] 0.000 sec [all/5/ext 0 (0,1000000000)] [ad_core]

[Mon May 20 01:21:50.400 2013] 0.000 sec [all/5/ext 0 (0,1000000000)] [ad_core]

[Mon May 20 01:21:50.409 2013] 0.000 sec [all/4/ext **21** (0,1000000000)] [ad_core]

[Mon May 20 01:21:50.633 2013] 0.000 sec [all/5/ext 0 (0,25)] [ad_core]

[Mon May 20 02:13:12.492 2013] 0.000 sec [all/5/ext 0 (0,1000000000)] [ad_core]

[Mon May 20 02:13:12.508 2013] 0.000 sec [all/5/ext 0 (0,1000000000)] [ad_core]

[Mon May 20 02:13:12.521 2013] 0.000 sec [all/4/ext 0 (0,1000000000)] [ad_core]

[Mon May 20 02:13:12.780 2013] 0.000 sec [all/5/ext 0 (0,25)] [ad_core]

[Mon May 20 02:13:21.341 2013] 0.000 sec [all/5/ext 0 (0,1000000000)] [ad_core]

[Mon May 20 02:13:21.453 2013] 0.000 sec [all/5/ext 0 (0,25)] [ad_core]

[Mon May 20 02:13:36.183 2013] 0.000 sec [all/5/ext 0 (0,1000000000)] [ad_core]

[Mon May 20 02:13:36.197 2013] 0.000 sec [all/5/ext 0 (0,1000000000)] [ad_core]

[Mon May 20 02:13:36.206 2013] 0.000 sec [all/4/ext 0 (0,1000000000)] [ad_core]
```

After 2AM, the 21 ads are not taken into account anymore ...

Could you please advice on how to track the problem ?
Is there any simple solution to maybe initialize the indexation ?

Comment: Can you share the index definition for your Ad model? And have you tried indexing the data again - if so, what's the output of the ts:index task?

Answer (score 0):

please find please what command "rake ts:index" returns me :

```
Generating Configuration to /home/kar/www/myapp/releases/20130520063222/config/development.sphinx.conf
Sphinx 2.0.4-release (r3135)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)
using config file '/home/kar/www/myapp/releases/20130520063222/config/**development**.sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'ad_core'...
WARNING: collect_hits: mem_limit=0 kb too low, increasing to 17152 kb
collected 0 docs, 0.0 MB
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.012 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
skipping non-plain index 'ad'...
total 1 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 5 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.1 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
rotating indices: succesfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=13500).
```

I think I have several problems here, the first one is that I'm taking development index file instead of production... I have to review my deployment procedure...

Comment: Are you running each of the rake tasks with RAILS_ENV set to production?